# How do I boot into Mendel OS on the sdcard with the Coral Dev board?

Tags: google-coral

From [this instruction](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/reflash/#flash-from-u-boot-on-an-sd-card) it looks like Google allows booting to the sdcard. However, the image they provided (recovery.img) is only an image to boot the board automatically to U-boot, after which you'll still have to flash the MendelOS to eMMC with USB.
I'd like to have the entire OS on the sdcard, that way it's easier to make copy of it and save the state of the OS.

Answer (score 3):

In order to create a MendelOS image that can be flashed in to an sd-card, you'll need to build the image your self. The steps for doing this:

- Cloning the Mendel repo's source from [here](https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md#check-out-the-repository)

```
    # Get the repo binary that's necessary to clone Mendel
    $ mkdir -p bin
    $ export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
    $ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
    $ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

    # Setup your git env
    $ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    $ git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

    # clone the repo
    $ mkdir mendel && cd mendel
    $ repo init -u https://coral.googlesource.com/manifest -b release-day
    $ repo sync -j$(nproc)
```

- Make sure that the build system on your host machine meets [these requirements](https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md#prepare-your-build-environment):

```
    # System
    A 64-bit CPU
    Kernel 4.15 or newer
    binfmt-support 2.1.7 or newer

    # OS
    The suggested OSes are: Ubuntu 18.10+ or Debian Buster or newer.

    # Install qemu
    $ sudo apt-get install qemu-user-static

    # Install docker
    $ sudo apt-get install docker.io
    $ sudo adduser $USER docker
```

- Build:

```
    $ sudo su
    $ source build/setup.sh
    $ FETCH_PACKAGES=true m docker-sdcard
```

After the build succeeds, you'll see your sdcard image in the out directory. You can install that to your sdcard using the `dd` command or some opensrouce tools like [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).

- Enable boot from the sd-card by switching the boot switch to as described ON OFF ON ON [here](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/reflash/#flash-from-u-boot-on-an-sd-card).

Cheers!

Comment: You state "After the build succeeds, you'll see your sdcard image in the out directory."  Are you referring to the complete sdcard_arm64.img?  Or simply the rootfs img buried within out's ROOTFS dir?