# booting google coral dev board from sd card

Tags: google-coral, mendel-os, guid-partition-table

I'm trying to boot the coral Dev board from an SD card. I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60894434/how-do-i-boot-into-mendel-os-on-the-sdcard-with-the-coral-dev-board),but it doesn't work for me. basically the boot process doesn't begin.

I'm using a 64gb SD card.
also, when when I try to flash the .img [made using google coral Dev documentation] file using balena etcher it gives me an error saying **missing partition table**

is this something to do  with the gpt partition table not being present in the OS image?